# Add a number to a element in a tensor rank 1 if a condition is met in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor rank 1, which may look like this: `[-1,2,3,-2,5]` now I want to add a constant to the absolut value of an element, if the element is negative. If the element is positive, nothing shall happen.

I know how to do this with a scalar like:

```
res = tf.cond(tensor < 0,\
lambda: tf.add(tf.constant(m.pi),\
tf.abs(tensor)),lambda: tf.constant(tensor)
```

Furthermore, I know how to iterate over a tensor with `tf.scan` , like here in the fibonacci example:

```
elems = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
initializer = (np.array(0), np.array(1))
fibonaccis = scan(lambda a, _: (a[1], a[0] + a[1]), elems, initializer)
```

But how can I combine the `tf.condition` with `tf.scan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

```
a = tf.Variable([-1,2,3,-2,5])
b = tf.where(tf.less(a, 0), tf.abs(a)+tf.constant(m.pi), a)
```